# gmdate not constant across servers?

Tags: php, date, unix, time, timezone

I've been working on a application that needs to do a lot of calculations with time.

To keep everything working a supposed to, I started with:

```
$dateToday = strtotime(gmdate("m/d/y"));
```

As I understood, this is supposed to return the GMT date. So whichever timezone the server is in, I should get the same time?

So, as I developed on localhost everything worked smoothly, but when I moved to a server in a different timezone, I started getting problems.

Echo'ing "$dateToday" on localhost gives me "1501192800", while doing the same on the server I get "1501214400".
That is the same as the 6h time difference between my local machine and the server.

So what am I missing here?

Thanks

Comment: Use DateTime (http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)

Comment: *"So what am I missing here?*" -- a good reading and understanding of what timezones are and how they affect the times computations and also the knowledge of PHP [date/time functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.datetime.php). I recommend you read about them but do not use them. Use the [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) and related classes instead. They are easier to use and provide complete support for timezones (while the old date/time functions do not.)

Comment: sample : date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Berlin');

Comment: I did start with using different date functions, but in then end I google'ed how to get GMT date on PHP and all stackoverflow threads pointed to gmdate. Going to try set the server timezone first with 
date_default_timezone_set("UTC"); and then use normal date functions. 
Also just to be sure, is there a possibility that the strtotime() is causing inconsistent offsets? I get a feeling that it might be part of the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> $dateToday = strtotime(gmdate("m/d/y"));
> ```
>
> As I understood, this is supposed to return the GMT date.

Not at all.

[`gmdate()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gmdate.php) formats a date using the GMT timezone. Since you called it with only one argument, it gets the date to format by calling [`time()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php).

[`time()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php) returns the current timestamp, i.e. the number of seconds passed since `Jan 1, 1970, 0:00:00 UTC`.

Then, `gmdate()` uses the format you provide in its first argument to produce a text representation of its second argument (the current timestamp as we saw). The value returned by `gmdate("m/d/Y")` is `07/28/2017`.

Then, `07/28/2017` is passed to [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) that tries to interpret it as a date and computes a timestamp from it. Because it doesn't contain any time component, `strtotime()` assumes the time is `0:00:00`.

And here comes the catch. Because the string provided as argument to `strtotime()` also does not contain any timezone information, PHP uses its configuration to assume a timezone. As you already discovered, running the code on two servers can produce different results because of different configurations.

For me, `strtotime(gmdate('m/d/Y'))` returns `1501200000` and this is the timestamp (the moment in time) when today (`July 18, 2017`) started on the `UTC` timezone (because the PHP I used for testing uses "UTC" as its [default timezone](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-timezone-set.php)). The values you get on different servers are the time moments when today started on their respective timezones.

If I run the same code with a PHP that is correctly configured for my timezone (`Europe/Bucharest`) I get `1501189200`. It is `10800` seconds before the value I use with `UTC` because `Europe/Bucharest` currently is on `UTC+3` (the regular `+2` of the Eastern Europe Standard Time plus `1` hour because of the Daylight Savings Time.

PHP currently provides a set of classes to handle date and time: [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) and the other [classes whose name start with `Date`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php) (find them in the documentation). They are easier to use than the old [date & time functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.datetime.php) and they also know how to handle the timezones (the old functions do not know).

Creating a `DateTime` object that stores the start of today in UTC timezone is  as easy as:

```
$dateToday = new DateTime("today 0:00:00", new DateTimeZone("UTC"));
```

You can as well create a `DateTime` object for "now" (in the desired timezone) and then set its time to `0:00:00`:

```
$dateToday = new DateTime("now", new DateTimeZone("UTC"));
$dateToday->setTime(0, 0, 0);
```

For the `DateTime` objects that are not modified in the code (they are only read) then you better create [`DateTimeImmutable`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetimeimmutable.php) objects. This class prevents accidental changing of the values it stores.

Comment: Thank you, I used 
$dateToday = new DateTime("today 0:00:00", new DateTimeZone("UTC"));
$dateGMTUnixToday =  $dateToday->format('U');
and now get a constant 1501200000!

Really appreciate the detailed explanation.

Comment: @VoidZA If you appreciate the answer, then upvote it. If it really helped then accept it

Comment: I do not have enough rep to upvote, don't see a "accept" button either.